# Request::segment(2) not working in livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I use the Request::segment(2); code in laravel livewire file but it's not get anything showing null, How I solve it. The app I run on local server.

```
Request::segment(2);
```

Please anyone help me to solve it, or ask me if you still not understend.

Comment: Show your URL please.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass **Request::segment(2)** value from component and make **Variable** of it in livewire controller and use in livewire view